# Wrapper for complicated Range manipulation

Tags: object-oriented, vba, reinventing-the-wheel, excel

I'm playing around with a class module to try to wrap up some complicated(ish) Range manipulation in Excel-VBA.

I might have a situation where I know the red range spans my target (the target is to have it's contents cleared) and all cells below the red range should go. Green areas are cells used that should not be deleted:

[image]

Another example: I only know the red cell - and all used cells just to it's right and below it are to be cleared. Again all green cells should be left alone:

[image]

Usually the above is done via manipulation by finding extreme cells (`rows.count...toLeft` etc) or the `CurrentRegion` property of `Range`. I've attempted to wrap that functionality into a Class Module:

Class Module Name: `TargetRange`

```
Private fCurrentRange As Excel.Range

''::
''::
Public Enum expandDirection
    toTheRight = 1
    fromTheRight = 2
    downwards = 3
    fromSheetBase = 4
End Enum



''::  read/write property - initial range
''::
Public Property Let CurrentRange(ByRef rng As Excel.Range)
    Set fCurrentRange = rng
End Property
Public Property Get CurrentRange() As Excel.Range
    Set CurrentRange = fCurrentRange
End Property


':: Expand
'::   this will need to use an enumerated type as options
'::
Public Sub expand(ByVal aDir As expandDirection)

Dim lstCell As Excel.Range
Dim lstRow As Long
Dim lstCol As Long

Set lstCell = Me.CurrentRange.Cells(Me.CurrentRange.Cells.Count)
lstRow = Me.CurrentRange.Cells(Me.CurrentRange.Cells.Count).Row
lstCol = Me.CurrentRange.Cells(Me.CurrentRange.Cells.Count).Column

If (aDir = downwards) Then

    Dim newLstRow As Long
    'newLstRow = lstCell.End(Excel.xlDown).Row
    newLstRow = Me.CurrentRange.CurrentRegion.Cells(Me.CurrentRange.CurrentRegion.Cells.Count).Row

    Me.CurrentRange = _
        Range( _
            Me.CurrentRange.Cells(1), _
            Me.CurrentRange.Worksheet.Cells( _
                newLstRow, _
                lstCol _
                ) _
            )
End If

If (aDir = toTheRight) Then

    Dim newLstCol As Long
    newLstCol = lstCell.End(Excel.xlToRight).Column


    Me.CurrentRange = _
        Range( _
            Me.CurrentRange.Cells(1), _
            Me.CurrentRange.Worksheet.Cells( _
                lstRow, _
                newLstCol _
                ) _
            )
End If


End Sub
```

I'm using it like this:

```
Dim r As TargetRange
Set r = New TargetRange
r.CurrentRange = wb.Sheets("foo").Range("A2")
r.expand downwards
r.expand toTheRight
r.CurrentRange.ClearContents
```

Questions:

1. As it stands could the class module be improved?
2. Are there some obvious methods missing from the class that could be added?
3. Is the whole thing a waste of time? (am I reinventing the wheel?)

Comment: How are you detecting what's green? It looks like you just take the input and count what it is. The green isn't empty is it?

Comment: @Raystafarian Green is just a sort of placeholder representing cells that are not allowed to be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your method, I would opt for a `Select Case` when determining which way to go.

```
Sub expand(ByVal rangeToExpand As Range, ByVal whatDirection As String)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long

    Select Case whatDirection

        whatDirection = "toTheRight"
            lastRow = rangeToExpand.CurrentRegion.Row
            lastColumn = Cells(rangeToExpand.Row, rangeToExpand.CurrentRegion.Column.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
            Set rangeToExpand = Range(rangeToExpand, Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))

        whatDirection = "fromTheRight"
            lastRow = rangeToExpand.CurrentRegion.Row
            lastColumn = Cells(rangeToExpand.Row, rangeToExpand.CurrentRegion.Column.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Set rangeToExpand = Range(rangeToExpand, Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))

        whatDirection = "downwards"
            lastColumn = rangeToExpand.CurrentRegion.Column
            lastRow = Cells(rangeToExpand.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, rangeToExpand.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rangeToExpand = Range(rangeToExpand, Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))

        whatDirection = "fromSheetBase"
            lastColumn = rangeToExpand.CurrentRegion.Column
            lastRow = Cells(rangeToExpand.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, rangeToExpand.Column).End(xlDown).Row
            Set rangeToExpand = Range(rangeToExpand, Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    End Select

    rangeToExpand.ClearContents
End Sub
```

That way you don't have to check every `if` every time. If my method is off for the directions, I probably misunderstood the goal of each string, but I don't see them in the original.

Then all you need to do is pass a range and a string to `expand` and it does all the work. Or make `expand` a function and pass the range back to the caller.

---

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, I'm not sure `.CurrentRegion` is the way to go. If working with `A1` in here - these are the CurrentRegions -

[image]

You can double check it, I'm on 2007 and just used

```
Sub testing()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1")
    rng.CurrentRegion.Select
End Sub
```

So anything that's a connection to the cell you've chosen, will be part of the `CurrentRegion` - even if it's all snakey like that.

So your first picture the `CurrentRegion` = `D5:G40` and the second picture `CurrentRegion` = `D4:L40` assuming the red cell(s) is the selection.

As to how to fix this - I'm not sure. Maybe ask for the input to be the "header" row, but that only works if you want to clear all the way down. It defeats the whole purpose of this. I didn't mean to point out a problem and not provide a solution - sorry.